# skipping loop in foreach with if statement

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this strange issue and I'm not sure how to title the question - suggestions?

Anyway, have an array that I'm looping over.

```
<?php

$array =  array(
   0 => array (
        'id' => '3'
        //etc        
   ),
   1 => array (
        'id' => '4'
        //etc        
   ),
   2 => array (
        'id' => '5'
        //etc        
   ), //etc
);

$numbers = '1,2,3,4';

foreach ($array as $arr) {

  if (! check_array($arr['id'], explode(',', $numbers)) ) {
    continue;
  }

  echo 'My ID is: '.$arr['id'];
  // output should only contain 3 and 4 since the rest didn't match

}

function check_array($id, $numbers) {
    if(in_array($id, $numbers)) {
        return true;
    } 
}
```

The idea is to skip the current iterations if `$arr['id']` does **NOT** matches with a value in the `$numbers` array.

It almost works fine except, because `check_array()` returns true or returns '1', for some reason it adds a 1 to my array of numbers.

This means that my array would now be 1,2,3,41. I had to `explode()` the `$numbers` array because `in_array()` expects parameter two to be an array, however, all I have is a comma separated string - so it must be converted to an array first.

Why does it add it on to the end? I essentially only want to extract `$arr` if it's `id` is equal to any of the numbers within `$numbers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**OP's comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795619/skipping-loop-in-foreach-with-if-statement/41795722?noredirect=1#comment70779707_41795722) below,

> I don't need just the ID's of the matched $arr's, I need every key that $arr has. I simply want to extract certain arrays within $array based on my $numbers var.

If you want to extract *matched inner arrays* from `$array` based on the `$numbers` ids, the solution would be like this:

```
$numberIds = explode(',', $numbers);
$resultArr = array();
foreach($array as $arr){
    if(in_array($arr['id'], $numberIds)){
        $resultArr[] = $arr;
    }
}

// display $resultArr array
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Here's the [**live demo**](https://eval.in/721773)

Comment: I don't need just the ID's of the matched `$arr's`, I need every key that `$arr` has. I simply want to extract certain arrays within `$array` based on my `$numbers` var.

Comment: I put //etc after the first field of `id` because the arrays I'm working with are rather large and aren't exactly needed in this demonstration. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: @ProEvilz Well, then `$arrayIds` contains all the ids of `$array`, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @ProEvilz So you want to extract matched inner arrays from `$array` based on the `$matchedIds`, right?

Comment: yes. Imagine if this was possible. SELECT * inner arrays FROM $array WHERE $arr['id'] = any numbers within $numbers. That's a pretty hackey' way of trying to explain it but I think it gets the point across.

Comment: @ProEvilz I've completely updated my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: This is pretty much perfect except how do I make `$resultArr[]` one level down in the `$array`? What I mean is that after for the foreach, I would have to do `$resultArr[0]['id']` instead of normally using `$resultArr['id']` and which ever other keys I wished to use. If it's possible to not use another foreach inside the existing one then even better.

Comment: @ProEvilz That's possible only if there are no elements other than `id` in inner arrays. Since I see `// etc` after `id` in every inner array, I believe there are other elements as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133761/discussion-between-proevilz-and-rajdeep-paul).